# How to remove 3 blank lines in a row from file in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Not sure if this is possible, but I'd like to use Powershell to accomplish the following: Remove the first 3 blank lines in any block of blank lines.

For example:

```
hello

this is a test




this is still a test


test
```

The expected output I'm looking for is:

```
hello

this is a test

this is still a test


test
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are looking for instances where there is 4 new lines in a row (3 for the blank lines, and 1 for the next line with text on it). You can do this with the `-replace` operator to perform a RegEx (short for Regular Expression) match and replace.

```
@'
hello

this is a test




this is still a test


test
'@ -replace "(\r?\n){4}","`n"
```

Not knowing if there will be a carriage return character as well as the new line character I used the regex match pattern of `(\r?\n){4}` which says to find zero or one Carriage Return characters followed by a New Line character, and to find that grouping 4 times in a row. If found, replace that with 1 New Line character. The output of this is exactly what you wanted. This will work on multi-line strings, so if you are performing this operation on a file you will want to use the `-raw` parameter when you read the file with `Get-Content`.